# Ошибка java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=2

Tags: java, база-данных, intellij-idea

[image: введите сюда описание изображения] при нажатии на test connection  `java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=2, Не удается найти указанный файл. com.intellij.execution.ExecutionException` проверял уже и переменную Path и никак не могу найти решение этой проблемы. Пишу на Java. Спасибо заранее.

Comment: Не хватает деталей. Наверное у вас проблема в подключении в IDE от JetBrains? Или в коде? В любом случае, надо указать в вопросе как именно вы пытаетесь подключиться.

Comment: через воркбенч работает  mssql а вот через идею не могу подключится к серверу

Comment: я так понимаю что в  IDE от JetBrains так как код раньше работал и сейчас работает а вот самого соединения бд с идеей нет. спасибо Вам Юрий за отзывчивость.

Comment: Всё же вам стоит добавить больше деталей. Мне кажется, что вы имеете в виду, что у вас есть код на Java, который подключается к БД и он не работает в IDEA, но работает в какой-то другой IDE? Воркбенч - это IDE? Или вы всё же пытаетесь в UI IDEA подключиться к БД, не из кода? И где БД? Локально или на удалённом хосте? Может у вас проблемы с сетью или брандмауэром? Без указания деталей почти ничего нельзя посоветовать кроме обращения в тех.поддержку IDEA

Comment: создаю бд на воркбенч и могу спокойно юзать ее , но при попытке подключится к серверу через идею - вылетает выше упомянутая ошибка

Comment: Судя по вот этой ссылке (https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/DBE-5762) вам надо прописать путь к JDK в `PATH` переменную системы

Comment: не решило проблему , под воркбенч подразумевал MySql WorkBench, бд локально

Comment: Не факт, что вы правильно попробовали. Я могу назвать несколько вариантов ошибки при добавлении Java в PATH. Если вы не будете детально описывать все нюансы помочь вам будет невозможно

Comment: зашел в свойства компьютера ->доп параметры системы->системные переменные ->Path->изменить->добавил путь C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2018.1\bin

Comment: Вы не то в PATH прописали. Надо прописать путь до Java. Это будет или `C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2018.1\jre64\bin` или `C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2018.1\jre64`

Comment: не помогло , старую ссылку удалил, новую вставил C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2018.1\jre64\bin

Comment: Вы не написали пробовали ли без `bin` в конце. Пожалуйста, пишите про все детали. Комментарии не бесконечны и я не могу каждый раз переспрашивать. Попробуйте также проверить правильно ли JAVA поставилась в системе. В консоли надо проверить вывод `java -version` и проверить, что прописана `JAVA_HOME`. В ней должно быть тоже же, что и в PATH. Также один из 2 вариантов. Возможно, надо где-то ещё в настройках IDE прописать путь до JAVA

Comment: `MySql Driver` установлен?

Comment: пробовал и с bin и с нет, не помогло. При прописывании java -version выводит версию джава 9.0 и еще пару строк о версии джавы.в  JAVA_HOME прописан путь без bin а в path тот же путь но с бин, добавил еще без бин.В каких настройках в идее прописать путь ? Settings->appearings&behavior->path variables прописано 2 переменные - котлин_бандлд и мейвен_репозитори

Comment: MySql Driver установлен? – Pro100Denysko- когда жму на MySQL драйвер -вылетает окно с настройками Data sourse and drivers и там я не пойму что делать

Comment: Data sourse and drivers вписываю адрес дравера на компе и все равно фейл

Comment: я уже в отчаянье , может кто скажет что не правильно у меня с переменными -переменная среды пользователя админ path -C:\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\bin;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-9.0.4\bin;%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Utilities 1.6\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.3.9\bin;%M2_HOME%\bin;% M2%\bin;C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\bin;C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2018.1\jre64\bin  системная переменая path такая же

Comment: java home C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-9.0.4\bin    m2 %M2_HOME%     M2_HOME C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.3.9

Comment: я так понимаю переустановка идеи ничего тоже не решит

Answer (score 1):

Помогла переустановка IntelijIDEA в моем случае. Но также одним из решений рекомендуется [проверять корректность настройки JDK](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544879). Очень похоже на [баг](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/DBE-5762) версии 2019.1.x